# Graphing $x^3+y^3\le 29$

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

I'm trying to graph the following system of inequalities

$$
\begin{cases}
1 \le x \le 3 \\
-1\le y \le 4 \\  
x^3+y^3\le 29 \\
y \ge e^x -2
\end{cases}$$

I'm using Geogebra. While the first two and the last one work okay, I can't seem to be able to visualize the third one, not even if I put it in the $y\le \sqrt[3]{29-x^3} $ form.

[image]

Maybe I'm missing some fundamental math concept. Any hints on what's not working?

Comment: Have you tried just the cubic inequality alone?

Comment: See also [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1+%5Cle+x+%5Cle+3+%2C+-1%5Cle+y+%5Cle+4+%2C+++x%5E3%2By%5E3%5Cle+29+%2C+y+%5Cge+e%5Ex+-2+).

Comment: Desmos successfully plots $x^3+y^3<1$, so this seems to be an issue of Geogebra rather than math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use $y\le (29-x^3)^{1/3}$ you get:

[image]